# What's sizeof(size_t) on 32-bit vs the various 64-bit data models?

Tags: c, 64-bit, sizeof, size-t

On a 64-bit system, `sizeof(unsigned long)` depends on the data model implemented by the system, for example, it is 4 bytes on LLP64 (Windows), 8 bytes on LP64 (Linux, etc.).  What's `sizeof(size_t)` supposed to be?  Does it vary with data model like `sizeof(long)` does?  If so, how?

---

References:

[64-bit data models on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models)

Comment: MSDN on [Common Visual C++ 64-bit Migration Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx) is helpful for Windows 64.

Answer (score 69):

size_t is defined by the C standard to be the unsigned integer return type of the sizeof operator (C99 6.3.5.4.4), and the argument of malloc and friends (C99 7.20.3.3 etc). The actual range is set such that the maximum (SIZE_MAX) is at least 65535 (C99 7.18.3.2).

However, this doesn't let us determine sizeof(size_t). The implementation is free to use any representation it likes for size_t - so there is no upper bound on size - and the implementation is also free to define a byte as 16-bits, in which case size_t can be equivalent to unsigned char.

Putting that aside, however, in general you'll have 32-bit size_t on 32-bit programs, and 64-bit on 64-bit programs, regardless of the data model. Generally the data model only affects static data; for example, in GCC:

```
`-mcmodel=small'
     Generate code for the small code model: the program and its
     symbols must be linked in the lower 2 GB of the address space.
     Pointers are 64 bits.  Programs can be statically or dynamically
     linked.  This is the default code model.

`-mcmodel=kernel'
     Generate code for the kernel code model.  The kernel runs in the
     negative 2 GB of the address space.  This model has to be used for
     Linux kernel code.

`-mcmodel=medium'
     Generate code for the medium model: The program is linked in the
     lower 2 GB of the address space but symbols can be located
     anywhere in the address space.  Programs can be statically or
     dynamically linked, but building of shared libraries are not
     supported with the medium model.

`-mcmodel=large'
     Generate code for the large model: This model makes no assumptions
     about addresses and sizes of sections.
```

You'll note that pointers are 64-bit in all cases; and there's little point to having 64-bit pointers but not 64-bit sizes, after all.

Comment: `size_t` cannot be the same as an unsigned `char`. 7.18.3.2 says that `size_t` must have a minimum maximum value of 65535.

Comment: Having 64-bit pointers just means that the underlying architecture supports 64-bit addressing.  An individual process in an OS might only be allowed to reserve up to 4GB RAM or less, which means size_t would only need to be 32-bit while pointers are 64-bit.  32-bit wide size_t wouldn't necessarily affect any operations as long as the CPU has the capability to add/subtract a 32-bit wide value to/from a 64-bit wide value.  So in a memory-constrained 64-bit environment, 32-bit size_t might be helpful/useful.  A 16-bit size_t in a 64-bit environment would probably be silly though.

Comment: @user904963 There's no requirement that `char` be 8 bits; It just has to be the size of a memory cell. For example, TI's C2000 line of DSP microcontrollers have a 16-bit `char` and all memory accesses are 16 bits wide.

Answer (score 17):

it should vary with the architecture because it represents the size of any object. So on a 32-bit system `size_t` will likely be at least 32-bits wide. On a 64-bit system it will likely be at least 64-bit wide.

Answer (score 5):

size_t is 64 bit normally on 64 bit machine

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments - I looked it up in the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), which says in section 6.5.3.4:

> The value of the result is
>   implementation-defined, and its type
>   (an **unsigned integer type**) is `size_t`,
>   defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other
>   headers)

So, the size of `size_t` is not specified, only that it has to be an unsigned integer type. However, an interesting specification can be found in chapter 7.18.3 of the standard:

> limit of `size_t`
>
> `SIZE_MAX 65535`

Which basically means that, irrespective of the size of `size_t`, the allowed value range is from 0-65535, the rest is implementation dependent.

Comment: I don't think that definition is true: size_t is simply result type of the sizeof operator and is required to be unsigned.

Comment: I think you have confused where an object with (it's address / a pointer) with it's size (a size_t).

Comment: @beef2k, You certainly can't say this in C. in C, an object merely is a region of storage, which does not inherently have a type. You can use calloc to create objects bigger than what size_t can represent

Comment: @beef2k: Your last statement is technically wrong. You can't say that sizeof(size_t) is necessarily >= 2 because the implementation can choose to define a byte as 32-bits, in which case sizeof(size_t) can easily be 1.

Comment: For clarification: `SIZE_MAX` is one of the macros in 7.18.3.2, whose *implementation-defined value shall be equal to or greater in magnitude
(absolute value) than the corresponding value given below, with the same sign.*, that is, 65535 is the minimum value which is an acceptable limit for the size of `size_t`, but it can be (and usually is) much larger.