# gcc Error: "Inputtools.c:85: error: conflicting types for ‘strcasestr’"

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I tried compiling ADPACK, written in C, on an Intel Mac running OX 10.6.4. I got the following error from the make command.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include -I/home/ozaki/include -c adpack.c
adpack.c: In function ‘main’:
adpack.c:223: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc -I/usr/local/include -I/home/ozaki/include -c Inputtools.c
Inputtools.c:85: error: conflicting types for ‘strcasestr’
/usr/include/string.h:88: error: previous declaration of ‘strcasestr’ was here
Inputtools.c: In function ‘strcasestr’:
Inputtools.c:96: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
Inputtools.c:96: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
Inputtools.c: In function ‘input_cmpstring’:
Inputtools.c:124: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type     ‘size_t’
Inputtools.c:124: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type     ‘size_t’
make: *** [Inputtools.o] Error 1
```

I tried recasting the size_t as a integer variable, as it is my understanding that size_t pretty much stores an untyped int, but the casting didn't work. Has anyone encountered such an error before? Should I try using a different version of gcc?

Thanks. Edited.
strcasestr is defined on line 85 as: 
static char* strcasestr(  char *str1, const char *str2)

It is defined in string.h as
char    *strcasestr(const char *, const char *);

Comment: The title points at the wrong error. The actual error that stops the compiler is `error: conflicting types for ‘strcasestr’`.

Comment: Could you show us what Inputtools.c is around lines 85, 96 and 124?  Otherwise, we're guessing.

Comment: As KennyTM says the error is in `strcasestr`. This function is an extension provided by your compiler (not defined by the Standard) and you're defining **another** with the same name. Change the name of your function or invoke the compiler in Standard mode.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I changed the name of the function strcasestr, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `%z` **modifier**, *if available*, e.g.

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( foo ) );
```

See: [How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably) (possible duplicate) for details

Comment: That was tried. I think KennyTM is right. The real problem is the conflicting definition of strcasestr.