# warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’

Tags: g++, gcc-warning, netcdf

I followed some similar posts to modify the code, however the warnings are still generated.

```
$ g++ ncfile.c -o ncfile -g -lnetcdf

ncfile.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ncfile.c:363: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’
ncfile.c:363: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’
ncfile.c:364: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’
ncfile.c:364: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’
```

In that block around line 363 and 364:

```
  for(i = 0; i < ndimsp; i++) {
    char * temp_name;
    size_t temp_len;
    temp_name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    nc_inq_dim(cid, dimids[i], temp_name, &temp_len);
    dimlens[i] = temp_len;
    if(dimids[i] == unlimdimidp) printf("\t\t%d %s   \tlength: %d (UNLIMITED)\n", i, temp_name, temp_len);
    else printf("\t\t%d %s   \tlength: %d\n", i, temp_name, temp_len);
    total_records *= temp_len;
    free(temp_name);
  }
```

What should I get rid of the warnings. It that harmful to the results?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the z modifier. Basically %zu for the size_t value.

this will be the outcome:

```
printf("\t\t%d %s   \tlength: %zu\n", i, temp_name, temp_len);
```

Take a look at this question:

[How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably)

Comment: You'll want `%zu`, not `%zd`, though, as `size_t` is an unsigned type.

Comment: wow completely missed that thank you the answer has been fixed.