# Difference between the output

Tags: c

I am having the confusion regarding the following code snippet because for the same string the output is 1 and 2 respectively.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  char str2[1]="a",str3[]="a";
  printf("%d %d ",sizeof(str2),sizeof(str3));
  getch();
}
```

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 6):

```
char str2[1]="a"
```

gives you a one-element array with content `{'a'}`.  This array is missing the nul terminator used to denote the end of C strings so you won't be able to use `str2` as a string.

```
str3[]="a"
```

gives you a char array that includes space for a nul-terminator - `{'a', '\0'}`

Answer (score 2):

Int the first case (`str2`) you set the size of the array to `1`; even though the initializer provided two characters, the second `char` is truncated to match the size of the array that you specified.

In the second case, you let the compiler pick the exact size, which in this case equals the size of the string literal.

The size of `"a"` is two, because you need an extra `char` for null terminator.

Note: [in order to print `size_t` in a portable way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524611/335858) you need to prefix `d`, `u`, or `x` with `z`, like this:

```
printf("%zd %zd ",sizeof(str2),sizeof(str3));
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate the use of the prefix z ?

Comment: @JaiHo `sizeof` expression is of type `size_t`. Format specifier `%d` expects an `int`, while `size_t` is not an `int`. Although printing often goes well without `z`, as in the code I posted on the last line of the answer, there are platforms where you would end up with incorrect printout or even a crash.

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C have types of character arrays that contain as many characters as explicitly specified in string literals plus the terminating zero.

For example string literal `"a"` consists from two characters `'a'` and `'\0'` and have type `char [2]`.

In this definition of array `str2`

```
char str2[1]="a";
```

you explicitly specified that it size equal to 1. So `sizeof( str2 )` will be equal to 1 that is `number_of_characters * sizeof( char )`

Take into account that such definition of `str2` is considered as an invalid definition in C++ because there is more initializers than initialized objects (that is elements of type char) because as I pointed out above string literals contain the terminating zero.

In this array definition

```
char str3[]="a";
```

the size of the array is not specified so it is calculated based on how many initializers are used. As string literal contains two characters ( `'a'` and `'\0`') then `str3` will be initialized with these characters and will contain two elements. That is `str3` will be an exact copy of the string literal. So `sizeof( str3 )` will be equal to 2.