# Getting length of character array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I know other questions have been asked about this topic but I could not find one for exactly what I am looking for. I am taking a course on C and was presented with the following challenge: "Create a new application and create four character arrays
to hold the following lines of text:

'Roses are Red.
Violets Are Blue.
C Programming is Fun. And Sometimes Makes my Head Hurt.'
Make sure your character arrays are large enough to
accommodate the character used to terminate C strings.
Using a correctly formatted printf() command and signifier,
output the string array values.
"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

   char firstLine [] = "Roses are red.";
   char secondLine [] = "Violets are blue.";
   char thirdLine [] = "C programming is fun";
   char fourthLine [] = "And sometimes makes my head hurt";
}
```

Instead of manually counting the number of characters in each array and then putting that number in the "[]", is there a way to determine the length of character in each string?

Comment: Justin, following other comments below, get in the good habit of compiling your code with **warnings** enabled in your compile string. At a minimum, something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o outputfile inputfile.c`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax:

```
char str[] = "Some text.";
```

already counts the right length for the string . You don't have to take any further action. Leaving the `[]` empty (in this context) means that the array has the exact size required to store the string.

You can inspect this by doing `printf("The size is %zu.\n", sizeof str);` , note that this will be `1` more than the result of `strlen` because strings have a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research by using `strlen`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char str [] = "Roses are red.";
   size_t len;

   len = strlen(str);
   printf("Length of |%s| is |%zu|\n", str, len);
   return(0);
}
```

output:

```
Length of |Roses are red.| is |14|
```

Source:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html

Comment: Note: `strlen(str)` returns type `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: When string are small, you will not encounter differences.  In this example --> no problem.  For a general solution, yes there is a problem.

Comment: @chux could you please gimme an example that lead me to problem?

Comment: @KickButtowski Simply declare `len` to be of type `size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart thank you I edited my answer and I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: Suggest using `"|%zu|"`  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably/2524675#2524675

Comment: What did your compiler say?  Hint: compare signed-ness of `size_t` and `"%zd"`.  If interested, find a draft spec of C11 via http://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/2410359