# Regarding the \0 character (or characters?) following strings in C

Tags: c, string, sizeof

Are both \ and 0 characters stored in the same location or in different locations in the end of the string?

```
main()
{
    char x[]="Hello\0";
    char y[]="Hello12";
    char z[]="Hello\012";
    char w[]="Hello1234";

    printf("%d %d %d %d", sizeof(x), sizeof(y), sizeof(z), sizeof(w));
}
```

Output:

```
7 8 7 10
```

Please explain the output of the code.

Comment: Note: better to use a matching format specifier: `printf("%zu ..., sizeof ...)`.

Comment: What do u want me to use? Doesn't sizeof() return int values?

Comment: Use `printf("%zu", sizeof(x))`.  `sizeof()` returns an unsigned integer type of `size_t`.  `size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>`.  In some environments, this integer takes up the same space as `int` and so `printf("%d", sizeof(x))` does not cause trouble as long as `sizeof(x) <= INT_MAX`.  In other environments, the space difference will immediately cause trouble.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably

Comment: Curious: Why did you think `sizeof()` returned `int` versus any other type?

Comment: I was not sure of what it returns. I randomly picked int data type , just to clarify with you :). Thank you..

Comment: Note: If you get into a situation where the type of the number is not well known or varies amongst platforms, like `clock_t, time_t` or the format specifier varies like with `int64_t`, here is a trick:  cast to the widest integer type and use `'j'`.  Example: `time_t t; printf("%jd", (intmax_t) t);`.  There are still a few issues with this approach, but it does solves many of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\0` in a C string is a single character, ASCII value `0`. All C string literals also include an implicit terminating `\0` character, regardless of what else is included in the string (even another `\0`).

`\012` is the octal character ASCII 10 (Line Feed)

So:

```
char x[]="Hello\0";      // 5 letters + your \0 + implicit \0 == 7
char y[]="Hello12";      // 7 letters + implicit \0 == 8
char z[]="Hello\012";    // 5 letters + \012 + implicit \0 == 7
char w[]="Hello1234";    // 9 chars + implicit \0 == 10
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the `\0` is an octal number and takes up one character position:

```
Array  Contents   Size
x      Hello\0    5 for the characters, one for the explicit \0, one for the implicit null terminator
y      Hello12    7 for the characters, one for the implicit null terminator
z      Hello\012  5 for the characters, one for the \012, one for the implicit null terminator
w      Hello1234  9 for the characters, one for the implicit null terminator
```

Comment: this answer is incorrect. \0 is not octal, it's an ASCII character.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow No. C parses it as octal, but since it's in a character string it gets treated as a character. Internally, of course, everything's a number, so there's no difference between the octal `\0` and the ASCII "null" character.

Comment: @APerson I amend my statement: it doesn't matter if it's octal. it's zero, no matter what base it's parsed as, and that doesn't affect the number of bytes it consumes. there is, in fact, a large difference between \0 (dec:0) and H (dec:72).

Comment: From the perspective of compilers that treat \ followed by exactly 1, 2 or 3 octal digits(digits 0-7) - `\0` will appear from the compilers perspective as a 0 value. `\00` and `\000` would be equivalent as well. But at the end of the day the compiler sees `\0` it will equate to the value `0`. But I have to agree that most lexers for C will treat `\0` as if it was an octal number with 1 digit '0'

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using implicit int return-type. Please desist.

Next, string literals are parsed thus:

First convert to characters, then concatenate neighboring strings, finally add an implicit sentinel 0.

```
char x[]="Hello\0";   // 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' 0                 sentinel-0
char y[]="Hello12";   // 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '1'   '2'         sentinel-0
char z[]="Hello\012"; // 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\012'            sentinel-0
char w[]="Hello1234"; // 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '1'   '2' '3' '4' sentinel-0
```

The escape-sequences used are both octal:

```
'\0'  for character 0
'\012'  for character 10
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated `\0` is an escape character and `\012` is a single escape character. In addition, all string in C automatically have a `\0` appended.

```
Array Index:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
          x:  H   e   l   l   o  NUL NUL
          y:  H   e   l   l   o   1   2  NUL
          z:  H   e   l   l   o   LF NUL
          w:  H   e   l   l   o   1   2   3   4  NUL
```

`NUL` and `LF` are the names given to octal 0 and octal 12 ASCII characters. see: http://www.asciitable.com/