# printing a 'triangle' of chars from string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, geometry

I'm trying to make a program that prints a string array as a triangle. I've looked online and can only find this as a number array and when I code it, prints out in a vertical line as below output shows. I'm new to programming so please be kind. I 'm looking for this type of triangle.

```
m y n a m
 e i s b
  r a n
   d o
    n
```

my code is this:

```
#define CHAR 25


main()
{
char string[CHAR] = "";
int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;

printf("Please enter your name\n");
printf("**********************\n\n");
fgets(string, CHAR, stdin);
puts(string);
pause;
cls;

for (i = 1; i <= CHAR; i++)//start of triangle
{
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        printf(" ");
    for (k = i; k <= CHAR; k++){
        printf("%c ", string[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}//end of triangle
```

I will most likely get a bad rating for such a stupid question but any direction would be great. Even if it a "hey idiot why are you doing this ..." Thanks to all the help!

Here is the output

i.e the string name is 'tom'

output:

```
o
o
o
o
o
 m
m
m
m
```

then a weird symbol character above the pause. I'm unable to post a pic yet apparently but this is what its showing.

Comment: What does the output look like? And it's `int main(void)`

Comment: Please share the error you are getting from compiler, if it is  a compile problem (I do not doubt it is).

Comment: *for (j = i; j < i; j++)* doesn't do anything. *i < i* is always false.

Comment: Also please do not declare multiple variables on single line. Since you are a beginner, it will prevent you from doing such a things as is declaring index variable as char - this will very likely result in overflow :-]

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the error. So I realized why it was breaking was because I had %s for the printf statement instead of %c. So now the output is multiple characters printed in a single line vertically as shown.

b
b
b
b
etc then

r
r
r
etc

Comment: Ask yourself: how many characters should be printed on the first line? How many on the second, third, fourth, etc? Now look at the loop that prints each line (the `for` loop involving `k`): does that loop print the correct number of characters?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to *show* the output and/or the specific error.

Comment: What if the length of your string is not a triangular number?

Comment: I truly apologize for all the mess. I'm still getting the hang of using the forum and whatnot. I corrected the question and the code along with the out put of an example name. again thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: @remyabel, the correct format for `size_t` is `%zu` not `%zd`. This is an unsigned type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code, although you appear to be on the right track. First off, please consult the [`printf` man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for the correct conversion specifiers to use. In general, if your format string does not match your arguments, it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to change this in two places:

`%d` should be [`%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably) because you are dealing with a `size_t`.

```
printf("The size of the string is %zu\n", strlen(string));
```

and you want to print a character, not a string.

```
printf("%c ", string[i]);
```

Also, you are trying to access an array with a char type, rather than an int type. Change those declarations:

```
char string[CHAR] = ""; int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;
```

Now to tackle your problem. First off, you're reading a string that potentially has spaces in it, but you do not take this into account. A rather inefficient approach would be to remove the spaces from the string before printing your triangle. A better approach is to ignore those spaces, i.e.:

```
if (string[j] == ' ')
// don't print them
```

Secondly, your outer loop gives potential to out of bounds array access:

```
for (i = 1; i <= CHAR; i++)//start of triangle
{
```

A over-simplified approach might look like:

```
int line_width = 6;

for (i = 0; i < line_width; i++)
{
    for (s = 0; s < i; ++s)
        printf(" ");
    for (k = i; k < line_width - 1; ++k)
    {
        if (string[j] == ' ')
            ++j;
        printf("%c ", string[j]);
        ++j;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The correct format for `size_t` is `%zu` not `%zd`. This is an unsigned type.