# Correct format specifier for return value of sizeof() in C

Tags: c, string, types, string-formatting

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("The 'int' datatype is \t\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("The 'unsigned int' data type is\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("The 'short int' data type is\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(short int));
    printf("The 'long int' data type is\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(long int));
    printf("The 'long long int' data type is %lu bytes\n", sizeof(long long int));
    printf("The 'float' data type is\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("The 'char' data type is\t\t %lu bytes\n", sizeof(char));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
The 'int' datatype is        4 bytes
The 'unsigned int' data type is  4 bytes
The 'short int' data type is     2 bytes
The 'long int' data type is  8 bytes
The 'long long int' data type is 8 bytes
The 'float' data type is     4 bytes
The 'char' data type is      1 bytes
```

But that's just the thing, the compiler requires that I use `%lu`(long unsigned int) rather than `%d`(int), as I would have expected. After all, we are just talking about single digit numbers here, aren't we? So why do I get the following error when using `%d` instead of `%lu`? Has it something to do with me being on a 64bit system(Ubuntu 14.10)?

```
helloworld.c: In function ‘main’:
helloworld.c:5:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'int' datatype is \t\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(int));
     ^
helloworld.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'unsigned int' data type is\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
     ^
helloworld.c:7:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'short int' data type is\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(short int));
     ^
helloworld.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'long int' data type is\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(long int));
     ^
helloworld.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'long long int' data type is %d bytes\n", sizeof(long long int));
     ^
helloworld.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'float' data type is\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(float));
     ^
helloworld.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The 'char' data type is\t\t %d bytes\n", sizeof(char));
     ^
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Comment: The `sizeof` yields a number of type `size_t`. It doesn't matter whether its result would fit in an `int` – it's defined like so. Don't use `%lu` either as it's not portable – the (always-)correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print size\_t variable portably?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to print the return value of [`sizeof` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof), which is usually of type `size_t`.

It appears, in your case, `size_t` is a `typedef` of `long unsigned int`, so it demands it's compatible format specifier `%lu` to be used. The returned value here does not matter, your problem is with the type mismatch.

Note: To have a portable code, it's safe to use `%zu`, on compilers based on C99 and forward standards.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that there were more specifiers than the usual ones you are told about in basic tutorials. I have never seen %z before. Are there many more?

Comment: @Totem welcome. sure there are. try to explore and you'll be amazed. :-)

Comment: Doesn't work for g++ 4.7.2: `error: ISO C++ does not support the 'z' gnu_printf length modifier [-Werror=format]`   Found the answer for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably - use `#ifdef` ...

Answer (score 7):

In C the type of a `sizeof` expression is `size_t`.

The `printf` specifier to use is `%zu`. Example:

```
printf("The 'int' datatype is \t\t %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

It has been possible to use this since the 1999 version of the C standard.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you have *undefined behaviour* due to mismatched format and data types.

You should use `%zu` for the type associated with `sizeof` (which is `size_t`).
For example:

```
 printf("The 'int' datatype is \t\t %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

This is particularly important if you intend to target both 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf