# Bitfield using 1 byte instead of 1 bit

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I am working on a networking application where I will receive 2 bytes and certain bits have specific significance. I am trying to implement that packet as a structure. The intent is to do a binary copy to object address and the fields of the packet are ready to be accessed. Here is a simple example representing my problem. When we try to inspect the size of the bitfield and structure they are not coming as expected.

```
#include <bitset>
#include<iostream>
struct a
    {
        std::bitset<8> b;
        uint8_t c;

    };
int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(a);
}
```

Output: 8

Expected Output: 2

Is this something specific to Bitset's implementation?

Generally, each element occupies only one bit (which, on most systems, is eight times less than the smallest elemental type: char).
(ref- [cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) )

compiled on Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 16.10.2

Comment: I expected `std::bitset` to have a saner implementation... You can either use another `uint8_t`, or use the actual bitfields, e.g. `uint8_t foo:1, bar:1;`.

Comment: The problem is that for some reason `sizeof(std::bitset<8>) == 8`,  it is unrelated to the class https://godbolt.org/z/Mhd1n7TYK . Maybe it is because efficiency, in some systems could be faster to implement 8-bits (or even less) operations with an underlying 8 byte type?
The good news is that  `sizeof(std::bitset<64>) == 8` and not 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of Microsoft Visual Studio' STL is open-sourced recently, you can check the implementation of `bitset` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/bitset#L477), we can confirm that the data structure is an `array`, the sketch:

```cpp
template <size_t _Bits>
class bitset { // store fixed-length sequence of Boolean elements
public:
    using _Ty = conditional_t<_Bits <= sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT, unsigned long, unsigned long long>;
    static constexpr ptrdiff_t _Bitsperword = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(_Ty);
    static constexpr ptrdiff_t _Words       = _Bits == 0 ? 0 : (_Bits - 1) / _Bitsperword; // NB: number of words - 1
    _Ty _Array[_Words + 1];
};
```

So for `std::bitset<8>`, the underly array is `unsigned long _Array[1]`. Then we get the size: 4. For the result of `sizeof struct a` we get 8, this is caused by the alignment around `b` and `c`, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815467/sizeof-alignment-in-c-structs) for reference about alignment.

As you are dealing with network applications, it's not suitable to use bitset here. To decode network protocol, it's better to use bit fields. There is a good example in seastar's [tcp decoder](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/include/seastar/net/tcp.hh#L227), you may take it as an example.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned long)` in Microsoft's compiler is 4 bytes, not 8 bytes. The extra bytes are more likely coming from alignment padding. The struct needs to be set to 1-byte alignment to eliminate padding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the great comment! I just forget the difference between Gcc and VC++. I have updated the answer now.

Comment: the alignment padding is more likely after the `c` field, rather than between the `b`and `c` fields. You can use `offsetof(a::c)` to verify that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have confirmed that the padding is after c field! Thanks for so many great suggestions!