# sizeof() & strlen() with implict null character

Tags: c, arrays, string, sizeof

If I am right, in the array `c` `\045` is being treated as single octal, whose corresponding ASCII character is `%`. Hence the `sizeof(c)` is 4.

Similarly in the array `d` `\099` should be treated as single octal value, whose corresponding ASCII character is `R` and the `sizeof(d)` should be 4, but it is not.

Can you please elaborate on what is happening in case of `sizeof(d)` and `sizeof(e)`?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char      a[] = {"12345"};
    char      b[] = {"12345\0"};

    char      c[] = {"12\045"};
    char      d[] = {"12\099"};
    char      e[] = {"12\0133"};

    printf("\ta         = %s  \n", a);
    printf("\tsizeof(a) = %ld \n", sizeof(a));
    printf("\tstrlen(a) = %ld \n", strlen(a));

    printf("\n");

    printf("\tb         = %s  \n", b);
    printf("\tsizeof(b) = %ld \n", sizeof(b));
    printf("\tstrlen(a) = %ld \n", strlen(b));

    printf("\n");
    printf("\tc         = %s  \n", c);
    printf("\tsizeof(c) = %ld \n", sizeof(c));
    printf("\tstrlen(c) = %ld \n", strlen(c));

    printf("\n");

    printf("\td         = %s  \n", d);
    printf("\tsizeof(d) = %ld \n", sizeof(d));
    printf("\tstrlen(d) = %ld \n", strlen(d));

    printf("\n");

    printf("\te         = %s  \n", e);
    printf("\tsizeof(e) = %ld \n", sizeof(e));
    printf("\tstrlen(e) = %ld \n", strlen(e));

    return (0);
}
```

Actual Results:

```
    a         = 12345  
    sizeof(a) = 6 
    strlen(a) = 5 

    b         = 12345  
    sizeof(b) = 7 
    strlen(a) = 5 

    c         = 12%  
    sizeof(c) = 4 
    strlen(c) = 3 

    d         = 12  
    sizeof(d) = 6 
    strlen(d) = 2 

    e         = 12
                      3  
    sizeof(e) = 5 
    strlen(e) = 4
```

Comment: The last character of `c` is `'\045'` i.e. `%`, not a `'5'` that follows `'\0'` and `4`!

Comment: In other words, if you had used `char c[] = {"ab\0de"};`, you would have gotten the result you expected.

Comment: Unrelatedly, `\099` is not a valid octal escape.  The octal escape corresponding to ASCII R is `\122`.

Comment: @zwol : that is not unrelated - that is exactly the problem.

Comment: [size_t must be printed out using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27296011/995714). Using the wrong format specifier invokes UB

Comment: @Clifford Unrelated to the previous two comments, I meant.

Answer (score 2):

`'9'` is not a valid octal digit.  The string `"\099"` is a `'\0'` followed by two `'9'` characters. Hence a string length of 2 and an array length of 6.  The `'\0'` being a string terminator.

The initialisation of `d[]` is equivalent to:

```
char e[] = { '1','2','\0','9','9','\0' } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to know a minute math before coding, that is, to know meaning of `octal`.

> The octal numeral system, or oct for short, is the base-8 number
>   system, and uses the digits `0` to `7`. - Wikipedia

So, how do you think to present a digit greater than `7` as octal? That's why your intention is wrong.

Additionaly, you need to be cognizant of characters/escape sequences corresponding to right mapping being used.

For example, glance at ascii table's oct values.

[image]