# Interpreting C char array as a long via a long pointer

Tags: c, pointers

The following program outputs `0x20001` which is `131073` in decimal.

```
int main()
{
    char foo[8] = {1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0};
    long int *derp = &foo;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long int)); // THIS OUTPUTS 8
    printf("0x%x\n",derp[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I know

- The long pointer dereference (i.e. `derp[0]`) will interpret all 8 bytes.
- Endianness is at play here. (I am on an Intel PC, so I am expecting little endian)

However, I cannot figure out how the above answer is reached.

Comment: I think this is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq why would it be undefined? &foo is simply an address value at the end of the day. And there are 8 bytes located there, which is what a long int comprises of.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq chars are always 1 byte = 8 bits.

Comment: g++ is complaining that `error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[8]’ to ‘long int*’ in initialization`, so this is actually probably invalid code, not merely undefined.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq use gcc without arguments. It will just give a warning, not error. I do not see how it is invalid, because addresses are addresses and bytes are bytes.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq same output when I cast the pointer (also warning goes away)

Comment: Using gcc 9.2.0, I get the same error.

Comment: It is not true that addresses are addresses and bytes are bytes.  Due to the strict aliasing rule, it is undefined behavior to use a `long int *` to point to an object that was declared as `char[8]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: @Fuad in C `char` is always 1 byte is true, but 1 byte can have more than 8 bits. See [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714). And you have UB on both of your `printf` lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading all the bytes of the number because you're using the wrong format specifier.

The `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int`, but you're passing a `long int`.  Formally, using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Also, casting the address of one type to the address of another type besides `char` and subsequently dereferencing that pointer is also undefined behavior.  That being said, here's what is probably happening.

Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes and a `long int` is 8 bytes, that means that only the first 4 bytes of the value are read.  Assuming again that your machine is little-endian, meaning that the least significant byte for an integer type comes first, the value you see is those first 4 bytes in the reverse order.

But again, this is undefined behavior.  You would most likely see something very different if you passed in a floating point value when the format specifier expects an integer or vice versa.  You could also crash your program if your `char` array isn't properly aligned for a `long`.

To fix this, change the format specifier to `%lx` which expects an `unsigned long int` however passing a `long int` is also permissible.

Comment: "the value you see is those first 4 bytes in the reverse order". But I cannot figure it out. Reverse order of the first 4 bytes would be 0201, which is not 131073.

Comment: @Fuad No, its 00 02 00 01 hex = 131073 dec which is the first 4 bytes in reverse order.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long int))` is a more serious issue. `sizeof` returns `size_t` which [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27296011/995714)