# sizeof doesn't give back the real length of an input

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, sizeof, strlen

I tried to test sizeof in my programm but it doesn't work.

```
char toFind[100];
fgets(toFind, sizeof(toFind), stdin);
printf(" %i", sizeof(toFind));
```

And what ever I put in it prints out 100.
What did I wrong.

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. Are you perhaps interested in `strlen`?

Comment: only thing you did wrong is use `"%i"` to print `sizeof`, [use `"%zu"` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296011/correct-format-specifier-for-return-value-of-sizeof-in-c). Your expectation of `sizeof` is wrong, it should indeed print out 100, that's the size of `toFind`.

Comment: If you do use `strlen` you might notice the size is off by one more than what you expect. That is because `fgets` includes the newline if it is there.

Answer (score 1):

`toFind` is an array of 100 chars. Each char is 1 byte. So `toFind` is 100 bytes.

Therefore `sizeof(toFind)`, which tells you how many bytes are in `toFind`, is 100. There is no problem. `sizeof` is working correctly.

You might be interested in `strlen(toFind)` which tells you how many bytes are before the first 0 byte. Since `fgets` puts a 0 byte after the characters it reads, this tells you how many characters `fgets` read.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` returns the size of a variable. It has nothing to do with what it contains. In fact, it's calculated at compile-time.

`fgets` populates the variable with a NUL-terminated string. As such, you can use `strlen` to find its length. Note that since this is the only way to know how much `fgets` read in, it makes it unsuitable for data that might contains NUL characters.

By the way, the correct format specifier for `size_t` (the type returned by `sizeof`) is `%zu`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` to output a value of the type `size_t` (the operator `sizeof` returns values of the type `size_t`) instead of the conversion specifier `%i`

```
printf(" %zu", sizeof(toFind));
```

The operator `sizeof` returns the size of the array `toFind` that is declared as

```
char toFind[100];
```

The size of the array does not depend on what is stored in the array.

Instead you need to use the function `strlen` declared in the header `<string.h>` like

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...


printf( "%zu\n", strlen( toFind ) );
```

But before using the function you should remove the new line character `'\n'` that can be appended to the entered string by the function `fgets`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...


toFind[ strcspn( toFind, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
printf( "%zu\n", strlen( toFind ) );
```