# Why (3 & 0x1111) = 1?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I do not see why 3 & 0x1111 = 1 ? It seems that:

> for any unsigned 32-bit integer i, i & 0x1111 should be i, right?

However when I tried this on ubuntu 14.04,  I got `3 & 0x1111=1`. Why?

```
int main() {
  unsigned int a =3;
  printf("size of a= %lu\n",sizeof(a));
  printf("value of 3 & 0x1111= %d\n",a & 0x1111);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: for any unsigned 32-bit integer i, i & 0xffffffff should be i

Comment: you are only masking the first bit so it is normal to become 1

Comment: @cerkiewny: For any `uint16_t`, but ot for a 32 bit type. `0xFFFF` is 16 `1`-bits only.

Comment: Are you confusing hexadecimal and binary _integer-constants_?

Comment: @Olaf. That is exactly what was happening :)

Comment: Another note: You want 8 hex chars to make a 32-bit number. OR:ing with 0xffff will give you identity for 16-bit numbers. For 32-bit numbers, you need 0xffffffff.

Comment: @SnildDolkow That makes sense. I need to revise K&R :)

Comment: @SnildDolkow: **OR**-ing with `~0` (all bits 1) yields `~0`, not identity. You mean AND-ing

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Too late to edit the comment, though. :/

Comment: @olaf  Btw, how can I control the number of bits of ~0? It seems that using ~0 is a more viable way than 0xffffffff?

Comment: to [print `size_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714) which is the result of `size_of`, use `%zu`. Using the wrong format invokes undefined behavior http://stackoverflow.com/q/2524611/995714

Comment: @zell: If you need a certain bit-width, you should use `~(uint32_t)0`. This will yield exactly 32 1-bits in the LSBs of the "larger type: `int`, `unsigned` or `uint32_t`, according to the [integer promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1), one of the more nasty (for the unaware) properties of C). `~0` will yield an `int` actually, I should have written `~0U`. Note that you can use any other `stdint.h` types (**never** rely on the standard C types to have a specific bit-width). Note that for signed types, things become more complicated.

Comment: @zell: Read the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) which type are used for integer constants. The link is the current C standard (C11) and a good reading anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Convert both of them to binary:

```
0x1111 = 0001 0001 0001 0001
3      = 0000 0000 0000 0011
```

When you `&` them bit by bit, what else do you expect?

Comment: I see. My bad. I kinda confused 1 and f :)

Comment: And if you want to write in binary instead of hex, you can do that: 0b1111111111111111 == 0xffff (but note that this is only 16 bits -- a 32-bit integer would have 8 hex digits).

Comment: It's a bit frightening to see what the vote differential is between two answers posted that were literally seconds away from each other.  Nevertheless, it's still a good answer :)

Answer (score 7):

In C, any numeric literal starting with `0x` is a hexadecimal number. So the bitmask you are using is `1111` in hexadecimal. In the mask, bits #0, #4, #8 and #12 are `1`s, and the rest are `0`s. That's why you're getting `1`.

```
0x1111 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 0001 0001 in binary
     3 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 in binary
------------------------------------------------
     1 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 after doing biwise AND
```

If you want to construct a mask with all `1`s, in hex, it should be

```
0xffffffff = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Answer (score 4):

3d = 3h = 11b

1111h = 0001000100010001b

so:

```
  0001000100010001b
&               11b
-------------------
                  1b
```

Answer (score 3):

`0x1111` is `0001000100010001` in binary. So `0x1111 & 3` is `0001000100010001 & 0000000000000011 = 0000000000000001`

Answer (score 2):

0x1111 is 4369, or as binary: 0001000100010001
So, 3 (0011) masked against that is going to be 0001.
Similarly, 19 (0001011) would be 17 (00010001)

Answer (score 1):

The & operator applies the binary and. The 0x means hexadecimal not binary so if we write 0x1111 into a binary we will get:
0001 0001 0001 0001 binary.
3 binary is 011

and

```
0001 0001 0001 0001 & 
0000 0000 0000 0011 =
0000 0000 0000 0001 = 1
```

Comment: binary 3 is not 101, rather it is 011

Comment: What does "does the binary" mean for the & operator? Your explanation regarding the operations doesn't make sense.

Comment: its "does the binary and"

Comment: That's better. Thank you.