# receiving an error in the function declaration

Tags: c, function, warnings

> i am receiving a an error and a warning in the following program

```
void reverse(char ss[],char s2[])
                  ^
1 warning generated
```

and the error is

> warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char *' instead of 'char []; [-Wsizeof-array-argument]

```
printf("%ld \n", sizeof(ss));
                       ^
```

> i am doing a reversing a character array in c

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #define MAXLENGTH 1000
    void reverse(char ss[],char reversest[]);
    int main()
    {
        char s[MAXLENGTH];
        int c;
        char d[MAXLENGTH];
        int i=0;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
          s[i]=c;
          i++;
        }
        s[i]='\0';
        printf("%ld \n",sizeof(s));
        reverse(s,d);
        printf("%s",d);
        return 0;
    }
    void reverse(char ss[],char s2[])
    {
        int i=0;
        int c=1;
        printf("%ld \n", sizeof(ss));
        for(i=0;ss[i]=='\0';i++)
        {
            for(int j=c-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                 s2[j]=ss[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

i am a newbie learning c. i believe i am doing something wrong but i couldn't figure out what it is

Comment: i didn't get into pointers yet. is there any other way around? @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @OP, Side issue: Curious, why did you select `"%ld"` to use with `printf("%ld \n",sizeof(s));` versus `"%u"`, `"%d"`, `"%zu"`, or any other specifier?

Comment: well @chux i know we use `%d` and `%ld` for integers and long integers respectively

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Hope you know `"%zu"` is best or `printf("%lu \n", (unsigned long) sizeof(ss));` as a weak alternative.  the return type of `size()` is `size_t`.  It is neither `int`, nor `long`, but _some_ unsigned type.

Comment: thanks @chux that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Note that on this line:

```
printf("%ld \n", sizeof(ss));
```

You are not printing out the number of bytes in the ss array.  You are just printing out the size of a pointer.  I believe if you fix this line, the warnings will go away.

Maybe you want this instead:

```
printf("%ld \n", strlen(ss));
```

Comment: so the `sizeof` is used to printout the number of bytes?

Comment: ...also the format should be `printf("%zu \n", sizeof(ss));`.If you are going to use an arbitrary integer format, you should cast `sizeof`

Comment: the sizeof operator tells you how big the operand is.  In this case, we can't tell that ss is an array.  It just looks like a pointer.  sizeof is a little weird, because when it can tell that the operand is an array and knows how big, it will return the number of bytes in the buffer.

Comment: I think you mean "the size of the buffer". `sizeof` has no way of knowing how you have used it.

Comment: what is `%z` used for ?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What are you talking about?  If he fixes his sizeof problem, the warnings will go away.  I gave him one way to fix it.  You probably caught my post when I hit submit early.

Comment: As for `%zu` please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: Also, here's a good link that explains about sizeof and arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: i replaced it with `strlen` now i am receiving

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'strlen'`

Comment: Add #include <string.h> up at the top of the code after #include <stdio.h>