# Segfault when passing structure from main() to worker functions

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

I am trying to write a simple game in C and I'm getting a SEGFAULT and have no idea why!

Here is the code for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PLYS_PER_GAME (1024)
#define MAX_LEN (100)

typedef struct {
   char positionHistory[MAX_PLYS_PER_GAME][MAX_LEN];
} Game;

void getInitialGame(Game * game) {
    memset(game->positionHistory, 0, MAX_PLYS_PER_GAME*MAX_LEN*sizeof(char));
}

void printGame(Game game) {
    printf("Game -> %p (%d)\n", &game, sizeof(game));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int hasGameEnded(Game game) {
    printGame(game);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Game game;
    getInitialGame(&game);

    if (hasGameEnded(game))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging with gdb but the results didn't get me too far:

```
C:\Users\test>gdb test.exe
GNU gdb 5.1.1 (mingw experimental)
<snip>
This GDB was configured as "mingw32"...
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\test/test.exe

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401368 in main (argc=1, argv=0x341c88) at fast-chess-bug.c:29
29              if (hasGameEnded(game))
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00401368 in main (argc=1, argv=0x341c88) at fast-chess-bug.c:29
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. for efficient function calls, printGame and hasGameEnded should take a pointer to a Game (like getInitialGame).

Comment: You should change the print specifier in the `printGame()` function from `%d` to `%lu`.

Comment: Welcome!  Thank you for including details in your question --- not everyone does.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how the community works, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys!

Comment: Well, your program compiles and runs without any problem (just a warning about using `%d` format instead of `%ld` for the `sizeof(game)`.  Apart of the fact of passing the complete structure by value to `hasGameEnded()` and to `printGame()` functions, I don't see anything irregular in your code (you are copying a 100Kb structure on the stack to pass it to either function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a stack overflow (really!), although I'm not sure.

1. You are declaring `Game game;` in `main()`.  That means all 102400 bytes of `game` are going on the stack.
2. Both `printGame` and `hasGameEnded` take a `Game game`, NOT a `Game * game`.  That is, they are getting a *copy* of the `Game`, not a *pointer* to the existing `Game`.  Therefore, you dump another 102400 bytes on the stack whenever you call either one.

I am guessing that the call to `printGame` is clobbering the stack in a way that causes problems with the `hasGameEnded` call.

The easiest fix I know of (without getting into dynamic memory allocation, which may be better long-term) is:

1. Move `Game game;` outside of `main()`, e.g., to the line just above `int main(...)`.  That way it will be in the data segment and not on the stack.
2. Change `printGame` and `hasGameEnded` to take `Game *`:

   ```
   void printGame(Game * game) {
       printf("Game -> %p (%d)\n", game, sizeof(Game));
       fflush(stdout);
   }

   int hasGameEnded(Game * game) {
       printGame(game);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

That should get you moving forward.

Comment: First post in stack overflow actually is a stack overflow! Oh, the irony... Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're likely running out of stack space.

C is pass-by-value.  So this code

```
int hasGameEnded(Game game)
```

creates a *copy* of the entire `struct {} Game`, most likely on the stack.

If the following code works, you ran out of stack space:

```
...

void printGame(Game *game) {
    printf("Game -> %p (%zu)\n", game, sizeof(*game));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int hasGameEnded(Game *game) {
    printGame(game);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Game game;
    getInitialGame(&game);

    if (hasGameEnded(&game))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Note carefully the changes.  Instead of passing the entire structure to `hasGameEnded`, it's now passing just the *address* of the structure.  That change flows down the call stack, culminating in changes to `printGame()`.

Note also that the [proper format specifier for `sizeof` includes a `z` modifier.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524675/4756299)  And I took the liberty of making it `u` for unsigned since a size can't be negative.