# Sizeof operator using with string to print its length

Tags: c, sizeof

When i run this code i m getting output as 4. But my string length is 3 why it is giving 4??

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {

    printf("%d",sizeof("abc"));
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `sizeof` tells you how much space your data item (a string in this case) takes, which includes the null terminator for the string. If you want the length of the string, use `strlen("abc")`.

Comment: Ohkay got it...

Answer (score 5):

Character strings in C include a null terminator, so the string "abc" actually occupies 4 bytes.

Comment: It means it is no use of sizeof operator is used in that way

Comment: @Shubham correct, it's of no use to use `sizeof` in a way that isn't according to its defined meaning.

Comment: @lurker - The sizeof operator on a character array returns the size of the array - which might be different from the length of the string - but this is a perfectly legal and valid use of sizeof.

Comment: @jeff ya it will be legal, but the way i am using or i am trying to get the length using this is wrong that's the mistake what i am doing... Actually this doubt clears my small but effective concept.

Comment: why is it 'no use', you can simply subtract one. However that only works in some cases of c strings. The better solution is strlen

Comment: @pm100 hehehe..sure but see na i am not actually doing what that function was meant for

Comment: A program may wish to clear the string using memset(s, 0, sizeof(s)); This is a valid use of sizeof.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin I was just indicating that `sizeof` isn't a string length function, but a memory usage function. Different meanings. Sure, it can be used to obtain the length of the string if one subtracts 1.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the string literal `"abc"` is `char [4]`.  It contains the characters a, b, and c, as well as a terminating null byte.  The value you're getting back reflects this.

If you want the length of the string, use `strlen`.

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen("abc"));
```

Note the use of the `%zu` format specifier, which expects a parameter of type `size_t`, as returned by `strlen` (and by `sizeof`).  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: String literals are not `const` qualified (though they are read only, i.e. changing their contents is undefined behaviour). Their type is `char[n]` with `n` being large enough for the string and a terminating zero byte. The type of e.g. `"abcd"` is `char[5]`. *Things may be different in that other language: C++.*

Comment: @pmg Thanks.  Removed the `const` reference.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you might get undefined behavior
because the `sizeof`' operator yields a result of type `size_t`,
and `%d` isn't necessarily the right format specifier.

Why 4? Because the initialiser is a string literal, it is a string, and does have a null terminator, if it ever exists as an object in memory.

Comment: No i am not getting any undefined behaviour..it is working good..why it will give undefined behaviour? Sizeof operator returns integer value na??

Comment: No, sizeof return size_t and correct format specifier is %zu.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family

Comment: @Shubham What makes you say you are "not getting any undefined behaviour".  Undefined behaviour is undefined; in the worst cases, it can result in you seeing what you expected (until you take your code somewhere else).

Comment: @toby Sorry its my mistake..yaa sure it will effect my code in long run...

Answer (score 0):

For strings in C I would recommend using the strlen(str1). It returns the length of the string WITHOUT the null termination character.

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
```

Comment: Yaa i got the answer