# What specifier is to be used to print BUFSIZ macro constant using printf in C (C89)

Tags: c, macros, printf, c89, ansi-c

Do we use `lu` and `unsigned long` cast like in:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)BUFSIZ); /* 512 */
```

and hope for the best? or there is another way?

And this is not a duplicate of: [How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)
simply because I don't know what `BUFSIZ` type is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one print a size\_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: you can cast it, then use the `size_t` advice from the duplicate :/

Comment: @AnttiHaapala seriously? how can I know that `BUFSIZ` is of type `size_t` if @Felix Palmen didn't give me the answer? My question is not about how to print `size_t`, its about `BUFSIZ` which I don't know even what type it is.

Comment: it is *a* size, which you can assume you can cast as `size_t` without loss of information.

Comment: @BiteBytes I *assumed* in my answer because `size_t` is the rational pick for it ...

Comment: You have not even *shown* `BUFSIZ`. If it is a macro with an unqualified integer value, then it is of type `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the C library defines it, but as it is a size, I'd treat it as `size_t`...

Comment: @FelixPalmen interesting, MSVC does define `BUFSIZ` as `512`.

Answer (score 4):

I assume `BUFSIZ` is always a value fitting into `size_t` and there are no other guarantees.

In that case: Yes, this is the *most correct* way to do it if you're limited to [c89](/questions/tagged/c89). The lack of a format length modifier suitable for `size_t` is one of the many shortcomings in this very old standard. In practice, if you're on a 64bit system with `LLP64` data model (this is, Win64), `size_t` is indeed larger than `long` and this code *can* break for large sizes. Thanks EOF for the hint. Still *in practice*: It probably should be defined reasonably and an I/O-Buffer sized `4G` or larger doesn't sound reasonable, so it really *is* unlikely to run into problems with the "casting to `unsigned long`" approach.

*Additional note*: There might be a valid reason to use this construct even with a compiler in [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) or [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) mode, and that is portability to the windows platform. Microsoft's `msvcrt` (the C runtime and standard library) doesn't support the `z` length modifier.

Comment: Pretty sure on 64-bit windows `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(unsigned long)`.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right. And then you're doomed because `ll` doesn't work either ...

Comment: The question specifies that `BUFSIZ` is used as a macro constant, so it may not be declared with type `size_t`. If the programmer needing to print this constant also has the freedom to redefine it, your solution seems reasonable. But if it exists in some legacy code or something, and it's not reasonable to change it (perhaps it's used in all kinds of strange scopes), then this would not be relevant.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler doesn't let you specify the standard, so it's not an option anyway.

Comment: Felix MSVC recent versions do support `%zu` format spec.

Comment: @WeatherVane not last time I checked, a few days ago, on windows 10.

Comment: That is a windows version, not a compiler version? I am on Windows 7 with MSVC 2015, having binned windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (7.21 Input/output )

```
SETBUF
```

> which expands to an integer constant expression that is the size of
>   the buffer used by the setbuf function;

It is unspecified what is the type of the constant.

On the other hand the standard function `setvbuf` can be used to specify a user-supplied buffer or the buffer allocated by the function. It has the following declaration

```
int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
char * restrict buf,
int mode, size_t size);
```

where the parameter `size` of the type `size_t` specifies the size of the buffer.

As the size can not be a negative number then you may output its value as having the type `size_t`.

Comment: Whether the size can be negative is irrelevant. Also, the type of the parameter to `setvbuf()` is not particularly relevant either, since an argument of any other integer type would automatically be converted to `size_t`, provided the prototype for `setvbuf()` is available, so `BUFSIZE` could be another integer type. In that case passing it to `printf()` is problematic because `printf()` is varargs.

Comment: @EOF You contradict yourself.  If you say that whether the size is negative is irrelevant then what will be with the size when it will be converted to size_t? So it is your comment that is irrelevant and wrong.

Comment: No. You simply do not understand the problem at hand. If you wanted to understand it, I'd recommend reading in the C11 draft standard n1570 about `6.5.2.2 Function calls`, particularly the intricacies of argument conversion with regard to varargs-functions.

Comment: @EOF Think about how negative value will be converted to size_t. And think about what the type of the parameter size of the function setvbuf that specifies the size of the buffer. And think also about what is the type of the value returned for example by the sizeof operator for a character array that is supplied to the function as an argument. So your comment does not make sense. It is irrelevant for my answer.

Comment: As I said, negative values are irrelevant. It's really simple: 1. Have `BUFSIZ` be of type `T1`. 2. Call `setvbuf()` with `BUFSIZ` as `size`. Here, since `setvbuf()` has a prototype, `T1` will be converted to `size_t` automatically. 3. Call `printf()` with `BUFSIZ`. Here, since `printf()` is varags, `T1` **will not be converted**, so whatever random insane unspecified type `T1` was, you would need to have the right `%`-conversion specifier for. You don't.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow did you mean `BUFSIZ` in your first code block?

Comment: @EOF It is very important that size can not be negative, It means that there is no great sense to use a signed integer type to output the size. If the size is negative then the automatic conversion yields a wrong value. So all your comments do not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There are more distinct, **incompatible** integer types than just `signed` and `unsigned`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I provided the description of the BUFSIZ from the standard. And then I provided the standard function that can be used to set the size of the buffer.

Comment: @EOF I already wrote that all your comments do not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Writing that does not make it true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is easy to find proof that `BUFSIZ` is certainly not always of type `size_t`. Consider the following fragment `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
BUFSIZ
```

Compile it on Linux and:

```
% gcc -E test.c|tail -n 2
# 2 "test.c" 2
8192
```

Thus, it certainly isn't of type `size_t` always. The constant migth be of type `int` but it might also not be an `int`, so the safest should be to assume that it can be *cast as `size_t`* since the argument to `setvbuf` is also of type `size_t`.

Then, use the advice from [How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: so it's not necessarily a `size_t`, so why you keep on insisting  that my question is a duplicate of "how to print size_t".

Comment: @BiteBytes it is `size_t` after `(size_t)BUFSIZ`. And of course, you cannot print it portably without any cast, because its type is not specified.