# Can you help me understanding this program?

Tags: c

Can you help me out to understand why I'm getting this output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main() {
char a[] = "Hello World";
char *p;
p=a;
printf("%d%d%d%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(p),strlen(a),strlen(p));
}
```

output:
1281111
(My OS is of 64-bits)

Saying that the above code should have shown 1241111(output) if It is compiled and 
ran on a 32-bit system. Due to 64-bit It shows 1281111.

In my First year, I saw this question and when I went to look for the output, 
I get 1281111.

But surprisingly above code's output has two options:1)12121111 and 2)1221111.(University Question).

Comment: It's a terrible question. Shows that universities still teach implementation details as unwavering truth.

Comment: 12121111? 96-bits computing? Also, there is `%zu` for `size_t` instead of `%d` which should have emitted a warning. I'd recommend using some spaces or any other separator between each number if you don't want to get confused with where each value starts or ends.

Comment: Sounds like the question was written for a time when 8 and 16-bit compilers were widespread. ;-) (`12 2 11 11` or `12 1 11 11` would be what you would expect in those cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `printf()` statement to the following, it's easier to see what's going on:

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",sizeof(a),sizeof(p),strlen(a),strlen(p));
```

On my system, this results in the output:

```
12
8
11
11
```

In other words:

- The size of the array is 12 bytes. (11 for the string, plus one for the `\0` character.)
- The size of the pointer is 8 bytes (because I'm using a computer with 64-bit memory addresses, as opposed to a 32-bit computer which would likely output `4`).
- When used as strings (`char*` pointers), `a` and `p` are equivalent. (because `p` points to `a`.) The length of the string `Hello World` is `11` (since `strlen()` doesn't include the `\0` byte at the end of the string).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You **still** cannot print a `size_t` with `%d`!

Comment: Yeah, I know it's incorrect. It compiled a warning per `%d`. ;-) It's undefined behavior, yes, but it's likely to print the correct output anyway. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family) for more details. I don't think there was a standard way to print `size_t` and `ssize_t` with `printf` format strings until C99 was standardized.

Comment: Cast to `unsigned long` and print with `%lu`, going to work for any conceivable architecture for this program.