# Weird behaviour of string size function or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, string, freeswitch, c-str

I am getting the wrong `std::string` size value.

```
statsd_link* statsd_init(std::string& host, int port) {
    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG,
         "statsd_init print data to %s:%d and length: %ld, %ld\n", 
             host.c_str(), port, strlen(host.c_str()), host.size());
}
```

And the output is:

```
2019-06-22 20:55:35.553331 [DEBUG] statsd_init print data to 127.0.0.1:8125 and length: 9, 0
```

Comment: Smells of UB being involved. How is `host` created and filled with data before it is passed to your function?

Comment: What does switch_log_printf does? The docs I found here https://docs.freeswitch.org/group__log.html#ga8b2e27a937f0e0fef00d1eae3ddedd14 seems to indicate that it needs more arguments. Have you tried extracting the two sizes in a different line and then feed them to switch_log_printf ? The other possibility is that something else is de-allocating or clearing the string, but then I would expect to see a sporadic issue.

Comment: `strlen()` and `size()` both return a `size_t`, and `%ld` is the wrong format specifier for that type. There is no standardized specifier for `size_t` in C++, but [there is one in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/). You should be using iostreams in C++ instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `%zu` is in C++11, since it incorporates the C99 standard library.  `%lu` (or even `%ld`) will probably work in **practice** on modern systems except for Windows (but don’t do that!).