# Array size mismatch - C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C to add random numbers to an array. The size of the array is given (say n = 250) and using rand(), I'm generating these numbers (range is 1 to 100).

```
int main()
{
    int n = 250;
    int array[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand()%100 + 1;
        array[i] = r;
    }
    printf("Output Size: %lu\n", sizeof(array));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, the result is-
Output Size: 1000

Expected result is 250. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 250 * 4 bytes int. See: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/sizeof-operator. Your 250 element array, where each element is an integer, and in your case 4 bytes per integer. So 250 * 4 = 1000

Comment: Gee, I feel dumb! Thanks for the clarification @OmidCompSCI :)

Comment: You only want to call `srand` once, at the start.  Don't call it every single time you create a random number.  It will result in poor random numbers, and it will slow tremendously.  Try to understand its purpose.  You're calling `time()` for *every single number you generate*.  It makes no sense.

Comment: @TomKarzes And if the loop runs in less than a second (which it almost certainly will), you'll probably get the same value in every element of the array. But in an case, `sizeof array` is not affected by the stored values. You could remove the loop without affecting the program's behavior.

Comment: Understood. I've edited the code and see the results now. Thanks again!

Comment: userx, Curious why did you select `%lu` to use with `sizeof(array)`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, exactly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Initially, I used %d but got an error "warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]" so I switched to %lu and got the output 1000.
Later, I used a variable to record the array size instead and used that with %d.

Comment: @userx also: [`%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: @userx `%lu` is the correct format for `unsigned long`, but `size_t` isn't guaranteed to be `unsigned long`. `%lu` works for your implementation, but is not portable. `%zu` is correct for any implementation. (The warning could be better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're expecting n as output (number of elements in the array); but you're doing it wrong. Currently, what you're getting is 250*4 = 1000 (i.e., size of int is 4, and the number of elements is 250).

Replace `sizeof(array)` with `sizeof(array)/sizeof (array[0])`

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57537491/5821408) to dive deeper.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(type)` returns the size, in bytes, of the *type*.
To find out size of array, you can do:

```
    printf("Output Size: %zu\n", sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Also, the type of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier instead of `%lu`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 250 elements array, each array element is of size 4 bytes.
250*4 = 1000.

And you don't need to call srand in loop.

read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/) article about srand.