# warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int*’ [-Wformat=]

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

While I'm compiling this simple program in GCC compiler I'm getting this error:-
**warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int*’ [-Wformat=]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Pointer\n");
    printf("*******\n\n");
    int i=3;
    printf("Address of Variable i : %u",&i);
    printf("Value stored in Variable i : %d\n",i);
    printf("Value stored in Variable i : %d\n",*(&i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use %p to print a pointer.

Comment: I'm getting this kind of Address :- Address of Variable i : 0x7ffc836a8534

Comment: I want integer type of address

Comment: Well, hex is conventional for a pointer.  It's a bit of a hack, but you might cast to unsigned long and print with %lu

Comment: Use `%z` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, wouldn't help here, `%z` is a modifier for int type `size_t`

Comment: @OlafDietsche a pointer and `size_t` are the same size on the vast majority of platforms

Answer (score 2):

Even without any extra option, gcc (9.3.0) shows a detailed warning message

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:7:38: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'int*' [-Wformat=]
    7 |     printf("Address of Variable i : %u",&i);
      |                                     ~^  ~~
      |                                      |  |
      |                                      |  int*
      |                                      unsigned int
      |                                     %n
```

So there's a mismatch between the format `%u` (unsigned int) and the argument `&i` (pointer).

Looking at [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) Conversion specifier

> **u** converts an **unsigned integer** into decimal representation dddd.
> ...
> **p** writes an implementation defined character sequence defining a **pointer**.

The proper format in this case would be `%p` for a pointer argument `&i`

```
printf("Address of Variable i : %p", &i);
```