# Want to check the bytes of memory occupied by variables in C

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

Beginner to C, using CodeBlock now. Just want to check the bytes of memory occupied by variables in C. I wonder why this error will occur here. Thank u!

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    short a;
    int b;
    long c;
    float d;
    double e;
    ch = 'a';
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
    d = 1.5;
    e = 1.5;
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(short));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(long));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(float));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(double));
    return 0;
}
```

error shows: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Werror=format=]|

when changing from `%d` to `%zu` or `%lu`, there are still errors shown:

```
error: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Werror=format=]
error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]|
```

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` type which is unsigned type and you should use the `%zu` format specifier ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524675/5457426))

Comment: Technically there are two problems with using `%d` for a `sizeof` result.  The main problem is that the sizes may be different.  Adding `z` will fix the size mismatch.  The second problem is that `sizeof_t` is an unsigned type, while `%d` expects a signed value.  Changing `d` to `u` will make it unsigned.  So the correct format to use is `%zu`.

Comment: changed but not working, some errors shown

Comment: @SteveSun Wow, you must be using a very old (or nonstandard) C library.  Maybe switch to a more compliant environment?  I believe `%zu` is required for C99 compliance.  I know `gcc` supports it, so there's an easy upgrade path.

Comment: @TomKarzes Just reload the complier yesterday and the errors were solved. Seems I got something wrong when installing the IDE. Many thx!