# Indices for Files

Tags: c++, file, filestream

What is the typical type used to store the index of a character in a file?  I'm currently using `long unsigned int`, but does this make sense?  Should I use `std::size_t` instead, or does that make even less sense?

Comment: what is index of a character?

Comment: @Gunner The `n`th character.  So if I had a file with the alphabet, `G` would have an index of 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike Seymor says, if you work with C++ io streams, std::streampos is the standard type for representing a file position. See

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streampos/

Note that std::size_t might not be correct. For instance, on a 32-bit system, std::size_t will be a 32-bit unsigned integer, whereas the system might well support files larger than 2^32 bytes = 4 GB.

FWIW, in the POSIX world, there is a (signed) integer type off_t which is used for representing file sizes and offsets. With various macros (e.g. _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 on Linux) one can redefine off_t to become a 64-bit type.

Answer (score 4):

`std::streampos` is the standard type for representing positions in character streams (including files).

Answer (score 2):

you are probably safe with both; basically you want to be able to store the max_file_size value;

the size in bytes of a file is defined as a long in struct stat; on 64bit platform size_t is probably always defined as a 64 bit number, on 32bit as a 32bit number, etc; unless you're using weird compilers.

check out [a size_t related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918787/whats-sizeofsize-t-on-32-bit-vs-the-various-64-bit-data-models)

I would go for the long. std::size is language specific and I tend to use an operation-specific type here. but again, I see no problem with using std::size_t as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ASCII characters, they wont have values above 127. Therefore, using unsigned char data type would suffice.

Comment: I'm not talking about ASCII characters; I'm talking about any given character's position in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want also represent "invalid index" somehow? If so, why don't just use `ssize_t`.