# Memory allocation error - in Linux but not OSX Unix

Tags: c, linux, memory, fault

I'm writing some code for a statistics package, and I start off by reading in data to a pointer array. I initialize the pointer and allocate sufficient memory using malloc; however, I sometimes get an error in the memory allocation at the end of the code below.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stats.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
FILE *fp, *outFile, *outBin;    // create a file identifier
size_t n, nbins; // # of data points
double *data; // pointer to hold data
double average, variance, *med; // stat returns
int medianComplete, histComplete, i; // return 1 on success
hist_t *Histogram;

// read in the number of bins from exe arguments
nbins = atoi(argv[1]);
nbins = (size_t)nbins;

// open the binary datafile and read in first value
// which is number of data points
// use exe input for filename
fp = fopen(argv[2],"rb");
fread(&n, sizeof(size_t),1,fp);

// allocate enough memory to hold all data
data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
if (!data)
    printf("Memory allocation error");
fread(data,sizeof(double),n,fp);
```

This program compiles and runs well on my personal machine (MacOSX), but fails due to a segmentation error when I try to run it on a Linux server. I used Valgrind to see if I could track down the error and I receive the following result.

```
==8641== Warning: silly arg (-501426814648844128) to malloc()
==8641== Invalid write of size 1
==8641==    at 0x4C2B20D: mempcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:956)
==8641==    by 0x4EA2F15: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1423)
==8641==    by 0x4E971D2: fread (iofread.c:44)
==8641==    by 0x40086D: main (runstats.c:28)
==8641==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

This is the first program I've ever written that uses pointers, and I'm at a loss for why it would work on one system but not the other.

Comment: Added in a test of the file pointer, and fopen() is successful.

Valgrind indicates that the error occurs when I allocate memory to data. The check I perform on data fails on the server, but passes on my own computer.

Comment: First thouht that comes when I see the question is: "Why is he doing this in C, when there are dozens of more suitable languages?.."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sizeof(size_t)` is platform dependent. On OSX with the default 32 bit code, `size_t` is 4 bytes. On 64 bit Linux, `size_t` is 8 bytes. If you're running on 64 bit Linux, you're reading a different `n` that you're reading on 32 bit OSX.

If you must use a binary data format, don't use the size of platform specific types as the field size. Decide whether the file header is 4 or 8 bytes, little or big endian, and use that consistently.

See:
[What's sizeof(size_t) on 32-bit vs the various 64-bit data models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918787/whats-sizeofsize-t-on-32-bit-vs-the-various-64-bit-data-models)

Comment: Ah! of course. That solved that bug. Thanks!

Now the error I'm getting from Valgrind is:
"Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation" pointing to my main declaration.

Comment: Are you reading with `fread` into a `size_t` still? If you're reading 4 bytes, consider using `fread` into a `uint32_t` from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely format your source prior to posting...

Use a debugger or printf the value of n after performing `fread(&n, sizeof(size_t),1,fp);`. Seems you don't get the value you expected.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'll definitely do that in the future.

I've checked this, n=20 as expected.

Comment: @dwv5009 Valgrind says it is not, assuming the code you posted is the one valgrind complains about. Did you check that n=20 by adding `printf("n=%zu\n", n);` right after the call to `fread(&n, sizeof(size_t),1,fp);` ?

Comment: @nos Yes, I did exactly that. The result is "n=20".

The answer below fixed it - the input file was written using size_t on a 32 bit system (4 bytes) and when I attempted to read in on the 64 bit system size_t was the incorrect size for my input file.

Comment: You should format your source prior to anything, you should __always__ format your source when coding.

Comment: @dwv5009 that line wouldn't print 20 on the 64 bit machine if so. (but if you used printf("%u\n", n); , or even "%d" instead of "%zu" , you might have seen 20, even if n wasn't actually 20)